# jquery blockui positioning

Tags: jquery, blockui

I'm using blockui to throw some forms up on my site but for some reason the blockui element is positioned about 20-30 pixels from the bottom of the screen. I tried, per the docs [(jquery blockui options for v2)](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#options) to reposition it using this code:

```
 $.blockUI({css: {top : '10px'}});
```

But that just yawned at me in a universe mocking kind of way and did nothing. The default, again, per the docs, is top : 40%. I don't want to wipe out all the blockui css, just reset the top positioning.

Answer (score 10):

I use this and the Load Message is positioned to the top right hand corner. Just play with the css to suit.

Hope this helps.

Rob

```
$.blockUI({
         message: '<img src="_assets/images/loading.gif" /><span style="margin-left:5px; font-family:arial;">Loading...</span>',
         fadeIn: 700,
         fadeOut: 700,
         timeout: 1000,
         showOverlay: false,
         centerY: false,
         css: {
             width: '150px',
             top: '10px',
             left: '',
             right: '10px',
             border: 'none',
             padding: '5px'
         }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks, I can't try it just yet, will give it a whirl tomorrow.

Comment: The key here is setting `centerY: false`. If you don't do this, then setting `css: { top: '10px' }` has no effect. But with `centerY: false`, the top property kicks in.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation gives this example:

```
$.blockUI({ css: { border = '5px solid red'} });
```

So I would try this:

```
$.blockUI({ css: {top = '10px'}});
```

Using an equal sign (=) instead of a second colon.  Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah, I tried the = sign with no luck, but +1 for the try... : )